# Displaying bounding box polygon from CSV using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, extents, json

I have a data file (.csv) with a minimum and maximum longitude and latitude. These 4 fields (roughly a few thousand rows) make up a bounding box. However, I am unsure of how to get this data to be displayed as a polygon. When I try to display data, I can only do points(X,Y). I need to create an Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax for each row of data.

I have brief experience with ArcPy, but would like to avoid unless that is your only solution. Also, I have this file also as a .JSON. I tried using the convert .JSON to features tool, but there was an error saying unable to parse when run.

[image: The image is an example of .csv data]

Comment: Do you have an column with a unique ID for each box? Using that, maybe Points to Line, then Feature to Polygon or Line to Polygon tools.

Comment: I could export the data and add a unique ID for each row. How would points to line work? Can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: This is a *very* basic task in arcpy. Avoiding it will only generate fewer convoluted solutions.

Comment: Vince, I am open to using ArcPy, have used some tools within it before. If it is basic, I'd love to use it

Answer (score 1):

If you add a unique ID to each row (bounding box / bbox), create points from the values in the table. You might have to create each bbox corner separately:

- box_lon_w, box_lat_s
- box_lon_w, box_lat_n
- box_lon_e, box_lat_n
- box_lon_e, box_lat_s

and merge them into a single feature class.

Each of these points will have an unique ID identifying them as belonging to a particular feature. You can then use the Points to Line tool to create a set of lines, then the Feature to Polygon tool. If there are overlapping bbox, you'll get odd results though. There are almost certainly better workflows than this, hopefully someone else will give you an answer with an easier/faster solution.